# Which value will be used in an always block?

Tags: verilog, hdl

Here is a verilog code: (This code is not for synthesis)

```
`timescale 1 ns / 1 ns

module test;
    reg r1, r2, r3, r4;
    reg clk_at_time, clk_from_clk;


    // Initialize signals 
    initial begin
      r1 <= 1;
      r2 <= 0;
      clk_at_time <= 1;
      #200
      $finish();
    end


    // Generating simple a clock (period time is 10ns)  (as expected)
    always #5
        clk_at_time <= ~clk_at_time;


    // Generating a clock based on the clk_at_time.
    // This clk_from_clk is always equals the clk_at_time (as expected)
    always @ clk_at_time
        clk_from_clk <= clk_at_time;


    // r1 and r2 inverted at all posedge event. (as expected)
    // r3 is constant 0 (as expected)
    always @(posedge clk_at_time) begin
        r1 <= r2;
        r2 <= r1;
        r3 <= clk_from_clk;
    end


    // r4 is constant 1  ???!!!??? HOW ???!!!???
    always @(posedge clk_from_clk) begin
        r4 <= clk_at_time;
    end

endmodule
```

And the waveform of the simulation:
[image: The waveform of the simulation]

In the code there are two clock: first is the traditional clock generated by time `always #5` the second is generated by this clock `always @ clk_at_time` The two clocks are always equal (as expected)

The strange thing that if I use the clk_from_clk in clk_at_time's block the previous value will be used of clk_from_clk. (OK), BUT if I use the clk_at_time in clk_from_clk's block the NEW value will be used of clk_at_time.

**EDIT**

Clarify:
See the waveform: `clk_from_clk` and `clk_at_time` are equals always.

See code: `r3` and `r4` are analog:

- `r3` is in `clk_at_time`'s block and driven by `clk_from_clk`
- `r4` is in `clk_from_clk`'s block and driven by `clk_at_time`

So if `clk_from_clk` and `clk_at_time` are really the same `r3` and `r4` should have be equal always. BUT See the waveform: `r3` is always 0 and `r4` is always 1

HOW? What is the rule?

Comment: _The strange thing that if I use the clk_from_clk in clk_at_time's block the previous value will be used of clk_from_clk. (OK), BUT if I use the clk_at_time in clk_from_clk's block the NEW value will be used of clk_at_time._ What? Are you talking about substituting `always @(posedge clk_at_time)` for `always @(posedge clk_from_clk)`? Please could you edit your question to make this clearer?

Comment: Can you make your question more clear? And also change the names of `clk_from_clk` and `clk_at_time`, as both are very confusing with each other.

Comment: I answered your same question of at [Electronics StackExchange](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/289604/17779). it is usually recommended to inform of a cross post within the StackExchange network.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the exact answer but I want to share an opinion, thinking from the simulations viewpoint. I'm writing this as an answer instead of a comment because it won't fit in comments.

I think this has to do with the finite element analysis nature of the simulation. At each time-step of the simulation, the simulator solves the circuit component by component. And since your `clk_from_clk` is derived frın `clk_at_time` the simulator will always evaluate the latter first.

The `r4` is evaluated after `clk_from_clk` so it will always have the value of 1. As for the`r3` it will be evaluated at the change of `clk_at_time` and simultaneous with `clk_from_clk` and have its previous value.